# angular showing forms depending on if I am logged in or not

Tags: angular, authentication

I am loggin in via Oauth2 authorisation. I receive the token in the webaddress which I am getting through the params.

Basically I want the login button to dissapear and logout button to appear.

when I use *ngIf="access_token" it doesn't work, right now I am using 
*ngIf="isLoggedIn==='yes'" to show the button. 
so when I get the accesToken I call a messageservice which has a Subject() that sends it back to the component with the updated "yes" or "no" variable.
There must be a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

U can specify store with observable and store there         value of type of boolean. One method will return isLogged as observable and second method will be for change value. Then in  any component you will only inject store. Read about them :) Under u have component using store to get currently logged status from your store.

Our component  :)

```
    isLogged = false
    Constructor(private utilityStore:UtilityStore)

    NgOnInit() {
    this.checkLoginSubscription =                        this.utilityStore.isLogged().subscribe( res = > {
    this.isLogged = res;
    });
    }
```